# Number of occurrence of a set of objects of size less than $r$ in $C(n, r)$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a set of $n$ distinct elements. Then, I take $C(n,r)$ without repetition. Then, I select a subset of $n$ of size $x$, called $s$, where $r>x$.

Is there a formula that represents the number combinations in $C(n,r)$ that contains all elements of $s$?

Example:

$n = [a,b,c,d]$

$r = 3$

$s = [a,b]$

C(n,r): (**a**,**b**,c), (**a**,**b**,d), (a,c,d), (b,c,d)

Number of times $s$ occurs in the combinations $= 2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a fixed subset of size $x < r$, to obtain a subset of size $r$ which includes the subset of size $x$, we must select $r - x$ of the remaining $n - x$ elements.  For instance, in your example, given a fixed subset $\{a, b\}$ of the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$, to obtain a subset of size $3$ which contains $\{a, b\}$, we had to select one of the remaining two elements of the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$, which can be done in two ways.  In how many ways can we select $r - x$ elements of the remaining $n - x$ elements?

> This is the number of ways we can select a subset of $r - x$ of the remaining $n - x$ elements, which is $$\binom{n - x}{r - x}$$

Comment: @LostinSpace  Why do you think this question does not meet quality standards?  The OP provided context by using an example to illustrate what was being asked.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!